# Is the area independent of $n$? $ A=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{tn}}(e^{-tn}(tn+1))}{t}~dt $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, applications

Consider the parametric equation $x=\frac{1}{t}e^{-tn}$ and $y=te^{-\frac{1}{tn}}.$ To integrate under this curve I put it in the proper form:

$$ A=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{tn}}(e^{-tn}(tn+1))}{t}~dt $$

I noticed that by changing $n$ from 1 to 2 to 3 that the area was the same!

> Is the area $A$ independent of $n?$

Do integrals like these have applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Integrals like these" is pretty vague, but here is a remarkable fact:

We can split the integral up as
$$A=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\mathrm{d}t+\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{1}{t}\mathrm{d}t$$
Which, using [an integral identity on DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) can be expressed in terms of modified Bessel functions -
$$A=2(K_{-1}(2)+K_0(2))$$
The modified Bessel functions obey the [recurrence](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29)
$$\frac{2\nu}{z}K_\nu(z)+K_{\nu+1}(z)=K_{\nu-1}(z)$$
From which we can conclude $K_{-1}(z)=K_1(z)$. So we have
$$A=2(K_{1-1}(2)+\frac{2\cdot1}{2}K_{1}(2))=2K_2(2)$$
The modified Bessel function has many applications in applied mathematics and physics.

Comment: This is only for $n>0$. When considering other $n$s the integral probably doesn't exist. So I would say, the answer to OP's question is, yes, the area is independent of $n$, as long as $n>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $u=nt$ so that $du=ndt$ gives
$$A=\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{u}}(e^{-u}(u+1))}{u}du$$
which is precisely the integral when $n=1$.

Comment: it was that easy?

Comment: do integrals like this have applications? (you forgot that part)

Comment: All I can think of is, with a normalizing factor, this could be some kind of probability distribution (because its area on the positive real line is constant)

Comment: what about the integral limits? Surely, $0\to 0$, but $\infty \to n\infty$. For $n\to 0$ the whole thing goes to zero.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that $n$ was an integer. At least this works fine if $n>0$.