# Closed form for $I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-e^x-e^{-x}+x}~ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Is there a closed form for this integral?

$$I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-e^x-e^{-x}+x}~ dx$$

I tried $u=e^x$ but it didn't simplify things much.

I think the closed form is a Bessel function, but I can't verify this directly.

I'd like to see the steps involved to reach the closed form.

Comment: The integral is a number, not a function.

Comment: Yes, it's modified Bessel, $K_0(2)$, and $u=e^x$ *does* simplify things.

Comment: @ProfessorVector WA says it is $2K_1(2)$.

Comment: @achille hui Oops, you're right, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the integral representation
$$
K_\nu  (z) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - z\cosh x + \nu x} \mathrm{d}x} \quad (\Re z>0)
$$
of the modified Bessel function to conclude that $I = 2K_1 (2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution actually helps quite a bit.
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-e^x-e^{-x}+x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Using $u=e^x$,
$$I=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-u-\frac{1}{u}+\ln u\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}=\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-u-\frac{1}{u}\right)\mathrm{d}u$$
Using the integral identity I referenced in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914649/is-the-area-independent-of-n-a-int-0-infty-frace-frac1tne-tn) this is
$$I=2K_{-1}(2)=2K_1(2)$$